# PSScriptAnalyzer is not working in my Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, psscriptanalyzer

I have it enable in settings (Script Analysis: Enable).

I have settings path sets to ScriptAnalyzerSettings.psd1

I can invoke Get-ScriptAnalyzerRule or Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer in PowerShell 
Integrated Console and it works (and showing warnings/errors according to rules).

On the other hand after "F1 + PowerShell: Select PSScriptAnalyzer Rules" nothing happens.
And of course there are no highlights in code.

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling PowerShell extension helped in my case.
Also, I've observed that for the extension to work, you have to have PowerShell Integrated Console running in the background.